# How to populate a combobox with years in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

I want to populate a combobox with year values between [1900, 2100]. What is the best way of doing this? I use ExtJS version 4.0.7.

Answer (score 0):

The docs are your friend: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

The second example shows how you can fill up a store (which will get bound to your combobox) with inline data. So all you should have to do is create a simple method which does a basic loop between the range of your desired years and add each iteration to the inline data of the store.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

To populate and define the store:

```
    var years = [];
    year = 1900;
    while (year<=2100){
         years.push([year]);
         year++;
    }

    var yearsStore = new Ext.data.SimpleStore
    ({
          fields : ['years'],
          data : years
    });
```

To assign store to a combobox:

```
{
                xtype : 'combo',
                itemId : 'yearsCmbx',
                fieldLabel : 'Years',
                store : yearsStore,
                queryMode : 'local',
                displayField : 'years',
                valueField : 'years',
                editable : true
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The years array should push the "year" field of var DOBYears. See below

```
var i = 0;
 var years = [];
 year = 1900;
    while (year<=2100){
        ** years.push({"year":[year]});**
         year++;
         i++;
    }
     var r = years ;

var DOBYears = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['year'],
    data : r
});
```

Comment: What version of ExtJS do you use?

Comment: maybe it has something to do with me using Ext.data.Store and you using Ext.data.SimpleStore. For some reason I was not getting proper results until i pushed **{"year":[year]}** to the years array

Comment: You should use simplestore. It won't work with regular store. I have tried it with the regular store before and realised that it is not working in that stuation.